# AWS CLI list-objects by specific date

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, groovy, command-line-interface

I'm trying to make a groovy script that list the objects on the AWS S3 that have been uploaded in the past three days. I installed the AWS CLI on the agent that the script runs on. The command I found that lists the objects by date is the following:

```
def cmd = "aws s3api list-objects --bucket (name of bucket) --query \"Contents[?LastModified>= '2018-10-16'].{Key: Key, LastModified: LastModified }\""
```

When I run this command on the agent directly from a putty session, it runs fine and lists the objects correctly. But when I try to execute the same command from the groovy script, I get the following error:

> Bad value for --query "Contents[?LastModified: Bad jmespath expression: Unclosed " delimiter:
>   "Contents[?LastModified
>   ^

I tried to replace the first and last quotation marks with single quotes but did not work. I tried to do the same thing with the quotation marks before contents and after `LastModified` but did not work as well. I tried passing `Contents[?LastModified>= '2018-10-16'].{Key: Key, LastModified: LastModified }` to a string variable and pass its value in the command after `--query` but that didn't work as well.

Comment: Please have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875204/jenkins-active-choice-parameter-how-to-execute-aws-shell-command-with-groovy. Also, please improve formatting of your question.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. So, I used the same method used in the example you sent me to define the command. My command now looks like this: `def cmd = ['aws', 's3api', 'list-objects', '--bucket', 'Bucket-Name', '--query', 'Contents[?LastModified >= \'${Date1}\'].{Key: Key , LastModified: LastModified}'];` It works fine when I replace `${Date}` with an actual date like `2018-10-16` but when i try to pass the date as a variable it seems like it is not reading the value of the variable and it returns all objects in my bucket.

Comment: so what I found out is that it passes the variable `Date` as part of the string so it is passing it as `$Date` instead of passing the value of the variable. But I can't pass the variable Date in a separate list element like this: `'[?LastModified >= ' , "\'${Date1}\'" , ']' ,`  because it will give me an error saying `Unknown option 2018-10-16`

Comment: Then try: `def date = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')
def cmd = ['aws', 's3api', 'list-objects', '--bucket', 'Bucket-Name', '--query', "Contents[?LastModified>='${date}'].{Key: Key , LastModified: LastModified}"]`

Comment: I tried this way but I'm getting the same results. `date` is not passed as a variable and then the value of it is not being read in the command.

Comment: Actually I figured out the problem. your way was correct i just had a typo. thank you so much!!

Comment: May I add it as an answer and have it accepted?

Comment: yes go ahead and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

Then try:

```
def date = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd') 
def cmd = ['aws', 's3api', 'list-objects', '--bucket', 'Bucket-Name', '--query', "Contents[?LastModified>='${date}'].{Key: Key , LastModified: LastModified}"]
```

Remember to always pass the command as a list, not string.